# Left Join query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to left join a table in Marketing Cloud Automation Studio Query.  I don't receive any errors but the expected data is not pulling into the data extension. The bolded statements are what are related to this addition.  The TaskOfficerEmail is not being populated although there is data there.

```
 Select distinct c.Customer_Community_Name__c as CustomerCommunityName
,v.Approval_Status__c as ApprovalStatus
, o.Id as MilestoneId
,v.Clear_to_Close_to_Borrower__c as Video
, v.Thumbnail__c as Thumbnail
, c.Spanish_Speaking__c as SpanishSpeaking
,  c.Customer_Community_Overview_URL__c as CustomerCommutyURL
, c.FirstName as FirstName
, c.Id as Id
, c.Email as Email
, p.Id as LoanPrefId
, u.Name as LOName
, u.Branch_Id__c as LOBranchId
, u.LO_NMLS_Number__c as LONMLS
, u.Branch_NMLS_Number__c as LOBranchNMLS
,u.Email as LOEmail
, u.Phone as LOPhone
, l.Id as LoanId
**, t.Email as TaskOfficerEmail**
, b.Co_borrower_E_mail__c as CoborrowerEmail

FROM Loan_Preference__c_Salesforce p

INNER JOIN CCM_Loan__c_Salesforce l on p.CCM_Loan__c = l.Id
INNER JOIN Contact_Salesforce c on l.Customer__c = c.Id
INNER JOIN User_Salesforce u on  c.OwnerId= u.Id 
INNER JOIN Video_Storage__c_Salesforce v on v.OwnerId = u.Id
INNER JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce o on o.Id = p.Opportunity__c
INNER JOIN III_Borrower_Info__c_Salesforce  b on b.CCM_Loan__c = l.Id

**Left JOIN User_Salesforce t on u.Id = o.Task_Officer__c**


WHERE 
l.id = 'a0O4100000AMJlcEAH'
```

Comment: Solved my own question!  was using Left JOIN User_Salesforce t on u.Id when it should be t.id!